# which classloader responsible for loading endorsed dir jars into JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I am asking this question for my knowledge. in java we have three class loaders bootstrap, system and extension class loaders. in this which one will do actual loading of endorsed jars?

Comment: Note: This directory will be ignored in Java 9.

Comment: Then how it handled in java 9, there is any new flow implemented to use?

Comment: You have to explicitly add any packages/classes you want to import from the class path to override a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the bootstrap class loader.

See the relevant [HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b5b3db42efca/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l335):

```
// Constructs the system class path (aka boot class path) from the following
// components, in order:
//
//     prefix           // from -Xbootclasspath/p:...
//     endorsed         // the expansion of -Djava.endorsed.dirs=...
//     base             // from os::get_system_properties() or -Xbootclasspath=
//     suffix           // from -Xbootclasspath/a:...
//
// java.endorsed.dirs is a list of directories; any jar or zip files in the
// directories are added to the sysclasspath just before the base.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the bootstrap classloader that loads the endorsed jars.

You can find more info at [Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/)
.

**To summarize its usage** - Java SE runtime environment will use classes in such JAR files to override the corresponding classes provided in the Java platform as it was shipped.  So the endorsed jars have higher preference than the JDK bundled jars.